# How to execute code after eclipse:eclipse in maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy, eclipse-plugin

I want to run some code after the eclipse goal of the eclipse plugin (eclipse:eclipse) runs.

The documentation of the eclipse plugin says that the generate-resources phase is execute prior to the eclipse goal, but it doesn't mention any phase that is executed **after**.
I wanted to include the code with the gmaven-plugin but I can't find the right configuration:

```
<execution>
    <id>delete_generated_sources_from_cp</id>
    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <providerSelection>1.7</providerSelection>
        <source>
            modifyClasspath.groovy
        </source>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: The problem here is that you calling a goal instead of the lifecycle of Maven. In other words the lifecycle of Maven is not running only a particular goal of the maven-eclipse-plugin and not the lifecycle in your project. Maybe you can give more details what you like to achieve so it might be possible to other opportunities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the plugin you want to execute to your project. If you add an execution of the plugin to the phase `process-resources`it will execute after the eclipse plugin if you run `mvn process-resources` (or any phase after process-resources)

You could also invoke them directly: `mvn eclipse:eclipse otherplugin:goal`

Comment: Adding the execution to the process-resources phase and calling e.g. `mvn install` also does the trick, but I wanted the code run after calling `mvn eclipse:eclipse` so there won't be any possiblity to make a mistake.

Comment: If you want to run mvn eclipse:eclipse the only option is the second one in my answer. If that is what you want, you should also remove the execution block from you configuration above otherwise it will also run when you invoke mvn install.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

eclipse:eclipse is not good way for executing the codes. I mean if you want to import project to eclipse, you should use 'eclipse:eclipse' otherwise you shouldn't.

Executing the code is depend on you codes; if this is web based, you should deploy it in your application server. If it has executable main class, you should execute it with 'java' command.

> I wanted to include the code with the gmaven-plugin but I can't find the right configuration

I could not understand what you mean. could you explain more ..

Comment: The code I want to execute is tightly related to the .classpath file which is generated by the eclipse plugin. The problem with the groovy integration plugin is that it generates a generated-sources/groovy-stubs folder which is added to the build path in eclipse and causes problems. A simple solution is to remove it from the buildpath. To do this automatically, I wanted to append some code after the eclipse:eclipse plugin has executed, which would modify the .classpath file.